# Iphone App Release with possible Patent or Licence issues

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Me and My friend had an app idea. I have been working on the app for a while, now it is finished and we want to release it on App Store. I have never published/released an app before.

Few weeks ago another app has been released by an enterprise company and their app is too similar to our app. The way their app works is almost identical to our app. Also incredible similarities on interface.

My question is if I try to release my app, what is the possibility of rejection of the app by  App store with the reason of Possible duplicate of another app. Or  rejection with any reason because two apps are almost identical.

Has anyone experience that kind of situation before?

Enterprise company's App  has been stated  **Patent Pending** on company website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, ask a lawyer if you want to be sure.

Secondly, you can submit your app and find out what Apple says.  There are thousands of duplicate apps on the App store.  If the app looks eerily similar to your app, just make sure whoever designed your app didn't "borrow" from their app, or work on the project, etc.

Also, patent pending means very little in the real world, as is.  It just means the company applied for a patent (stating that and not having applied is illegal).  When, and only when a patent is approved, can legal action be taken.  And it also can't be enforced retroactively.

Lastly, be prepared.  If it's a big enterprise that put the app out and they think you're copying, etc, just get your ducks in a row.  Find the date you registered you app name, created documentation, all that fun stuff.  And good luck.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the legal advice you are looking for, but you should just submit your app even if it bares a striking resemblance to another app.  If people didn't release products that are similar to another where would be no Facebook and no Android.  Become successful with your product, then fight any legal battles that will follow because others are jealous of your success.

If Apple rejects it, then address the reason why it was rejected and try again.